# Ext js message box - not opening in IE7

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using Ext js MessageBox to display some warning messages in my application. The code looks as below:

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'Confirm',
            msg: "Some warning message",
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
            fn: function(btn) {
                if (btn === 'ok') {
                    //Some functionality
                    if (condition) {
                        **showTaxIdWarningMessage();**
                    } else {
                        //some code
                    }
                } else {
                    // some code
                }
            }
        });
```

The `showTaxIdWarningMessage();` function is as below:

```
function showTaxIdWarningMessage() {
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Confirm',
        msg: 'Second warning message',
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
        fn: function(btn) {
            if (btn === 'ok') {
                //some functionality
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This code works perfectly on Chrome and IE11. Meaning, I am able to display both the warning messages without any issues.

The real problem arises when I have to display these warning messages on IE7 (The application is viewed in compatibility mode on higher environments). On IE7, I'm left with the error message below:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'addCls' of undefined or null reference
ext-all-dev.js (133868,21)
```

The Ext js version 4 is used in the application. I am trying to debug to find the issue but so far, I am not able to find anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made a naive mistake here. Modifying the code as below worked for me:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
            .......
            functionWithMessageBoxCode();
            .......
        });
```

The above change made my code work properly on IE7 and Chrome as well. Posting it here, thinking it might help other rookie developers working Ext js.

Answer (score 1):

[According to their doc](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.0/index.html#!/guide/getting_started]), Ext.js 4 only supports IE6 and above. If you are supporting IE5 I would recommend you to use a different framework.

Comment: Jonny, I made a mistake while posting my question. It's IE7, not IE5. I edited the question. Thanks for your response.